# Prove that if E, F, and G are mutually independent, then E and F ∪ G are independent

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Prove that if E, F, and G are mutually independent, then E and F ∪ G are independent.

Seeing as I am aware of the definitions of mutually independent (p(A)=p(B)=p(C)) and independence p(A∩B)=p(A)p(B), I am not clueless. Though if I could have some help getting started on and doing this proof, it would be appreciated.

Comment: $F\cup G = (F\cap G)\cup (F^c\cap G)\cup (F\cap G^c)$

Answer (score 1):

Must show: P(E(FuG)) = P(E)P(FuG)

P(E(FuG)) = P(E(FG u $F^c$G u F$G^c$)) = P(EFG u E$F^c$G u EF$G^c$) = P(EFG) + P(E$F^c$G) + P(EF$G^c$) = P(E)P(FG) + P(E)P($F^c$G) + P(E)P(F$G^c$) = P(E)[P(FG)+P($F^c$G)+P(F$G^c$)] = P(E)P(F u G)

Apologies for horrible formatting. I think it's ugly but clear enough.